Prove that a given symmetric set of bilinear equations has only symmetric solutions.
Conjecture:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose that, for all $k \in [n] = \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, we have
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x_{i+1} y_{k-i} = 1 \tag{1}$$
and
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} x_{i+1} x_{i+k} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} y_{i+1} y_{i+k} . \tag{2}$$
Then $x = y$.

Equivalent Conjecture: Let $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be lower triangular Toeplitz matrices.
(I.e., for all $1 \le j \le i \le n$, $X_{i,j}=x_{i-j+1}$ and $Y_{i,j}=y_{i-j+1}$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and, for all $i < j$, $X_{i,j}=Y_{i,j}=0$.)
Suppose that $$XY=A,\tag{1'}$$ where $A\in\{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ is the lower triangular matrix of all ones (i.e., $A_{i,j}=1 \iff i \ge j$), and $$ X^TX e_1 = Y^TY e_1, \tag{2'}$$ where $e_1 = (1,0,0,\cdots,0)^T$ is the first standard basis vector.
Then $X=Y$.

Essentially, the conjecture gives $2n$ unknowns and $2n$ equations and asserts that there is a unique solution, up to sign symmetry (i.e., if $x,y$ is a solution, then $-x,-y$ is also a solution).
Here's what I know:

There always exists a solution with $x=y$. Namely, we can inductively (for $k=1,2,\cdots,n$) define $$y_k = x_k = \frac12\left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k-2} x_{i+1} x_{k-i}\right). \tag{3}$$ This corresponds to the closed form $$x_k = y_k = 4^{1-k} {2k-2 \choose k-1}. \tag{4}$$
For $n=1$ it is easy: We have $x_1y_1=1$ and $x_1^2=y_1^2$. The only solution is $x_1=y_1=\pm 1$.
For $n=2$ it is messy but doable: From Eq. 1 with $k=1$, we have $x_1y_1=1$, which gives $y_1=1/x_1$. From Eq. 2 with $k=2$, we have $x_1x_2=y_1y_2$, which gives $y_2=x_2x_1/y_1=x_2 x_1^2$. Eq. 2 with $k=1$ gives $x_1y_2+x_2y_1=1$. Substituting in our expressions for $y_1$ and $y_2$ gives $x_1^3x_2+x_2/x_1=1$, which rearranges to $x_2=1/(x_1^3+x_1^{-1})$. Eq. 1 with $k=1$ gives $x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2$. Substituting all our expressions in gives $$x_1^2 + (x_1^3+x_1^{-1})^{-2} = x_1^{-2} + x_1^4 (x_1^3+x_1^{-1})^{-2},$$ which simplifies to $x_1^{12}=1$. This has only two real solutions $x_1 = \pm 1$. Both solutions give $x=y$ overall.
Note that over the complex numbers the $n=2$ case has 12 solutions! I'm not interested in complex solutions, but this tells us that the problem is nontrivial.
Eq. 1 constrains the first $n$ coordinates of the convolution of $x$ and $y$.
Eq. 2 with $k=1$ gives $\|x\|_2^2=\|y\|_2^2$.
Summing Eq 2. gives $\big( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \big)^2 = \big( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \big)^2$.
If Eq. 2' gave us $X^TX=Y^TY$ (instead of just equality of the first columns), then from the diagonals we would have $x_1^2 = (X^TX)_{n,n}=(Y^TY)_{n,n}=y_1^2$ and, for $2 \le k \le n$, we have $x_k^2 = (X^TX)_{n-k+1,n-k+1}-(X^TX)_{n-k+2,n-k+2} = (Y^TY)_{n-k+1,n-k+1}-(Y^TY)_{n-k+2,n-k+2}=y_k^2$. This would imply $\forall k ~ y_k=\sigma_k x_k$ for some $\sigma \in \{-1,+1\}^n$.
For $n=3$, sympy returns 36 solutions, but only two are real. Assuming the correctness of sympy, this verifies the conjecture for $n=3$. Alas, the code is too slow for $n=4$.


Have you attempted to give a matricial expression of your two families of constraints ?

@JeanMarie I added an equivalent version in terms of matrices.

Thanks for the connection (Toeplitz matrices)

Update: I still believe this conjecture, but I managed to prove what I wanted to prove a completely different way, so I no longer need this.
